# Python Pandas - Email column has values with the delimiter on it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, delimiter

So I have this big .csv in my work that looks something like this:

```
Name| Adress| Email| Paid Value    
John| x street | John@dmail.com| 0|
Chris| c street | Chris@dmail.com| 100|
Rebecca| y street| RebeccaFML|@dmail.com|177|
Bozo | z street| BozoSMH|@yahow.com|976|
```

As you can see, the .csv is seperated by pipes and the email of the last two people have pipes in it, causing formating problems.
There are only 2 customers with this problem but these fellas will have more and more entries every month and we have to manually find them in the csv and change the email by hand . It is a very boring and time consuming process because the file is that big.

We use python to deal with data, I researched a bit and couldn't find anything to help me with it, any ideas?

Edit: So what I want is a way to change this email adresses automatically through code (like RebeccaFML|@dmail.com -> RebeccaFML@dmail.com). It doenst need to be pandas or anything, I am accepting ideas of any sort. The main thing is I only know how to replace once I read the file in python, but since these registers have the pipes in it, they dont read properly.

Ty in advance

Comment: Why not use a different delimiter for your csv?

Comment: @ddejohn I'm guessing he doesn't make the file

Comment: @Chris please try not to assume people's gender online. That's a fair assessment, but if this person has write access to the file, they could just go in and change the delimiter.

Comment: @ddejohn The word 'he' is merely used in the colloquial sense for sake of brevity.

Comment: What needs to be changed? The pipes in the email address, or using pipes as delimiters?

Comment: @ddejohn please don't assume that everybody on here identifies as a programmer

Comment: lol okay but for real, this industry has legitimate issues with diversity. It's really not that hard to switch to gender-neutral pronouns.

Comment: It's all fine people, I'm a dude. But moving on, yeah the IT department makes the file, I dont really have control over that. 
What I want to do? I want to replace the pipes in the emails somehow, but when reading the csv the email gets all chopped up and values get out of place or simply just breaks that line.

Comment: Are these pipes *actually* part of their email addresses, or is it an issue with the IT department's data entry/cleaning process? If it's the latter, I think you should bring this up with them and tell *them* to fix it.

Comment: We already talked to them ages ago, things just move VERY slowly. I hope it is a typo and not theyr actual email but I have no way to know :p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass regex as separator in `read_csv`. [`\|\s*(?!\@)`](https://regexr.com/67637) will split on pipes (possibly followed by spaces), but exclude pipes followed by an at sign. You can subsequently remove the remaining pipes with `replace`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''Name| Adress| Email| Paid Value    
John| x street | John@dmail.com| 0|
Chris| c street | Chris@dmail.com| 100|
Rebecca| y street| RebeccaFML|@dmail.com|177|
Bozo | z street| BozoSMH|@yahow.com|976|'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep = r'(?<!\@)\s*\|\s*(?!\@)', engine='python',index_col=False,usecols=range(4)).replace('\|','', regex=True)
```

Output:

|  | Name | Adress | Email | Paid Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | x street | John@dmail.com | 0 |
| 1 | Chris | c street | Chris@dmail.com | 100 |
| 2 | Rebecca | y street | RebeccaFML@dmail.com | 177 |
| 3 | Bozo | z street | BozoSMH@yahow.com | 976 |

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  Guess this is my cue to learn regex but, if you don't mind answering just one more, I discovered an e-mail like this today: Ryan@|gmail.com . 
In this case I would need to disregard pipes that come after an '@' too, how can we do that with regex?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer to include a negative lookbehind for `@`

Answer (score 1):

Create a generator for custom rows
Here it supposed to set email column at 3rd place, but u can adapt it

```
import pandas
def rows(path: str, sep: str = '|'):
    with open(path) as f:
        header = [*f.readline().split(sep), None]
        for row in f:
            row = row.rsplit('\n', 1)[0].split(sep)
            if len(row) > len(header):
                yield [*row[:2], ''.join((row[2], row[3])), *row[4:]]
            else:
                yield row
pandas.DataFrame(rows('data.csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to remove the troublesome pipes (`|`) in your text file using a regular expression:

```
import re

data = '''Name| Adress| Email| Paid Value    
John| x street | Jo|hn@dmail.com| 0|
Chris| c street | |Chris@dmail.com| 100|
Rebecca| y street| RebeccaFML|@dmail.com|177|
Bozo | z street| BozoSMH|@yahow.com|976|'''


pattern = re.compile(r"""(\|[^|]+?) # the previous pipe, i.e. a pipe followed by one or more not pipe characters
                          \| # the troublesome pipe
                          ([^|]*?@.+?\|) # the  rest of the email until the next pipe """, re.VERBOSE)


res = pattern.sub(r"\1\2", data)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Name| Adress| Email| Paid Value    
John| x street | John@dmail.com| 0|
Chris| c street | Chris@dmail.com| 100|
Rebecca| y street| RebeccaFML@dmail.com|177|
Bozo | z street| BozoSMH@yahow.com|976|
```

Notice the added extra pipes in the `data` value for the sake of testing. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/9QydAw/1) for extra explanation and debugging.